# How get only the values from list comprehension in a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, list-comprehension

Here is a list, `n_list`

```
n_list = [2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 1, 9]
```

**Problem Statement**:

I would like to get the result from list comprehension but the output should just be the value, not the list. Basically, result without writing a separate for loop for it.

**Simple Solution but not what I want**:

If I had to only print the result, I can do this way, using `*`:

```
print(*[val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1])
```

**Current Issue**:

However, while applying it to a function, I am getting error:

```
def singleVal(n_list):
    return(*[val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) ==1])
    
singleVal(n_list)
```

> Error: Can’t use started expression here.

Is there any way to get only the values from list comprehension in a function?

**Expected Output**:

Ultimately, should be something like the following code but in a function form and using list comprehension method:

```
result = [val for val in a if a.count(val) ==1]
    for i in result:
       return I
```

**Return**:

> int: the element that occurs only once

Comment: When functions return multiple values, unless explicitly set otherwise, they are always returned as a tuple.   What are you trying to do with the return value?

Comment: The * operator can be used only as a part of a function call. `return` is not a function. Simply remove the *.

Comment: I am trying to get the value of list using list comprehension: ```result = [val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1]
for i in result:
    print(i) ```

Comment: What is the value of a list if not the list itself?

Comment: just added a sample list in the question. I would like to get the value `5` because it is the only single value as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DYZ if I remove `*`, I will get a list as output, but I want only the value of list.

Comment: But what if there are other values that only appear once?

Comment: Also, there is a more effitient way of doing that (what your doing is O(n^2))...you can count each element and keep that count in a dictionary...or use the `Counter` class from `collections` which do exactly this, and then look for the elements with value 1

Comment: @JorgeMorgado still, it should only result all the comma separated values but not in a list.

Comment: I think you are complicating the matter by asking how to *get* the value of a list (which is really just the list again), when you're really just asking how to *print* the values contained in a list without the brackets. A simple hack would be `print(str(n_list)[1:-1])`

Comment: So what you want to return? a tuple? I still don't get it. Can you write an expected output?

Comment: Ohh if it is what @Grismar says then you can do something like: `return repr(ans)[1:-1]` where `ans` is the result of the list comprehention

Comment: You confuse returning from a function and printing within the function. In the former case, use `return [...]` (no *, no parentheses). In the latter case, use `print(*[....])`.

Comment: @Grismar, @Jorge please try to print updated list using the above mentioned following code (I would like to have result in similar format if not comma separates:   ```print(*[val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1])
 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do here is to return the list, and then use the `*` operator to print it:

```
def singleVal(n_list):
    return [val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1]
    
print(*singleVal([2, 4, 4, 5, 2]))  
# 5
```

If you are very certain that there will be exactly one value to return, you can write your function to just return that one value, e.g.:

```
def singleVal(n_list):
    return next(val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1)
    
print(singleVal([2, 4, 4, 5, 2]))  
# 5
```

Note that the above version of `singleVal` will only return the first unique value if there is more than one unique value in `n_list`, and will raise `StopIteration` if there are zero unique values.

If you want your function to return the list in the form of a single string, you can use `join`:

```
def singleVal(n_list):
    return " ".join(str(val) for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1)
    
print(singleVal([2, 4, 4, 5, 2]))  
# 5
```

Note that converting the result to a string makes it easy to print, but very difficult to do anything else with (you'd need to use `split()` and `int()` to convert it back to a list of numeric values).

If you want the function to just print the result rather than returning it, put the `print` inside the function, and don't have it return anything:

```
def singleVal(n_list):
    print(*(val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) == 1))

singleVal([2, 4, 4, 5, 2])
# 5
```

Comment: Your solution is definitely insightful. However, my aim is to write everything with a function (basically your first solution, but without using separate `print`)

Comment: Then why not just put the `print` inside the function to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

```
def singleVal(L):
    result = [str(val) for val in L if L.count(val)==1]
    return '\n'.join(result)
```

Comment: this I have already shown above, however, I need help with writing this in the form of a function and get the same output

Comment: @sargupta  take a look at the edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking, with a one-element tuple on the left-hand side:

```
result_list = [val for val in n_list if n_list.count(val) ==1]
singleVal, = result_list  # the comma makes the LHS a tuple
return singleVal
```

If `result_list` doesn't contain exactly one element, this will throw an error: either `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)` if there is more than one element, or `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)` if the list is empty.